# Монтирование раздела жёсткого диска linux

Tags: linux, mount

Необходимо примонтировать раздел диска в ещё одну директорию. Допустим, у нас есть раздел /dev/sda1, который смонтирован в /boot. Каким образом можно смонтировать этот раздел, например, в /mnt/tmp. Вариант : mount --bind /boot /mnt/tmp не подходит, так как при монтировании известно только имя раздела. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А симлинк не подойдет?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

просто монтируйте, да и всё. демонстрация:

```
$ mount | grep sda1
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw,relatime,block_validity,barrier,user_xattr,acl,stripe=4)
$ mkdir /tmp/boot
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /tmp/boot
$ mount | grep sda1
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw,relatime,block_validity,barrier,user_xattr,acl,stripe=4)
/dev/sda1 on /tmp/boot type ext2 (rw,relatime,block_validity,barrier,user_xattr,acl,stripe=4)
$
$ ls /boot /tmp/boot
/boot:
config-4.9.0-3-amd64  initrd.img-4.9.0-3-amd64  System.map-4.9.0-3-amd64
grub                  lost+found                vmlinuz-4.9.0-3-amd64

/tmp/boot:
config-4.9.0-3-amd64  initrd.img-4.9.0-3-amd64  System.map-4.9.0-3-amd64
grub                  lost+found                vmlinuz-4.9.0-3-amd64
```